# How to fix missing labels in base R barplot

Tags: r, label, bar-chart

Hi i have trying to plot a barplot of number of staffs, however some of the labels on x axis is missing. How to fix this

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(Name = c("John", "Jacky", "Jill", "Sam", "Arthur", 
"Aaron", "Jacob", "Joseph", "Martin", "Alan", "Albert", "Clare", 
"Frederick", "Florence", "David", "George", "Michael", "Doughlas", 
"Andrew", "Brian"), Clinc = c("DMMTC", "DMMTC", "DMMTC", "DMMTC", 
"CKDMTC", "CKDMTC", "CKDMTC", "CKDMTC", "Warfarin MTC", "Warfarin MTC", 
"Warfarin MTC", "Warfarin MTC", "Respiratory MTC", "Respiratory MTC", 
"QSC", "QSC", "QSC", "Pain MTC", "Pain MTC", "Pain MTC")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

summary(dat)

head(dat)


counts <- table(dat$Clinc)
barplot(counts, main="Placements",
        xlab="number of staffs",)
```

Comment: How about clicking zoom button?

Answer (score 3):

Anandapadmanathan, this is sensitive to the actual size of the plot window. If you expand it to a larger size, you should see all labels. Some may be hidden due to over-lapping text boxes. For instance, this is your code but with a much wider plot window.

[image: barplot]

Unfortunately, while I don't have an easy fix for why one or more names are "missing" from your plot, you have the ability to add labels arbitrarily.

First, did you know that `barplot` returns the X values for the center of each bar? Oddly enough, they are not integers:

```r
bp <- barplot(counts, main="Placements", xlab="number of staffs")
bp
#      [,1]
# [1,]  0.7
# [2,]  1.9
# [3,]  3.1
# [4,]  4.3
# [5,]  5.5
# [6,]  6.7
```

We can use these to place some text *manually*.

Starting with a too-narrow plot:

```r
# left, unchanged
bp <- barplot(counts, main="Placements", xlab="number of staffs")
```

We can add some text manually. For this, know that `xpd=NA` allows us to put text (and points) outside of the normal plotting window. Also, `adj=` is a vector of "x alignment" and "y alignment", where 0.5 is centered, and in this case, -4 is "bump down approximately 4 heights". You'll need to play with this to get it to what you want. (See [`?par`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html) for help on `xpd`, and [`?text`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/text.html) for help on `adj`.)

```r
# middle, just for testing
bp <- barplot(counts, main="Placements", xlab="number of staffs")
text(bp, 0, names(counts), xpd = NA, adj = c(0.5, 4), col = "red")
```

Lastly, since we can now see that it's the 2nd and 5th label being omitted, we can just target those.

```r
# right, fixed
bp <- barplot(counts, main="Placements", xlab="number of staffs")
text(bp[c(2,5)], 0, names(counts)[c(2,5)], xpd = NA, adj = c(0.5, 4), col = "red")
```

[image: three barplots side by side]

Is it perfect? No. Is it beautiful? Perhaps not. But this allows you to regain something of what you've lost. (I personally feel that alternating the height of x-labels can be a good thing, especially when some of them are wider than you want.)

Answer (score 2):

Here are four other ways to deal with the labels not showing:

1. Make the label text smaller:

   ```
   barplot(counts, main="Placements", xlab="number of staffs", cex.names=.7)
   ```
2. Change the size of the plot window:

   ```
   dev.new(width=10, height=6)
   barplot(counts, main="Placements", xlab="number of staffs")
   ```
3. Use a horizontal bar plot by increasing the left margin:

   ```
   oldp <- par(mar=c(5.1, 8.1, 2.1, 1.1))
   barplot(counts, main="Placements", xlab="number of staffs", horiz=TRUE, las=1)
   par(oldp)
   ```
4. Increase the bottom margin and plot the text at an angle:

   ```
   out <- barplot(counts, main="Placements", names.arg="")
   title(xlab="number of staffs", line=4)
   text(out, rep(-.1, 6), names(counts), srt=45, pos=2, xpd=NA, cex=.75)
   ```