# How can I see the name of the categories in the barplot?

Tags: r, plot

How can I get smaller letters to see the full name of the different categories? (I can only see all the names if I do a "plot", not a "barplot")

The idea is to have a ** barplot ** with the full names of the 4 categories (which you can see in the graphic "plot" below).

```
plot(table(somalia$strike_status))
```

[image: Plot]

```
barplot(table(somalia$strike_status))
```

[image: Barplot]

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix missing labels in base R barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58759916/how-to-fix-missing-labels-in-base-r-barplot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the argument `cex.names` (as one of the arguments to the call to `barplot`) to define the character extension of the names on the x-axis. For example, if you set `cex.names = 0.5` this will reduce the size of the characters by half of the default size and thus render them more readily visible in the plot.